# Unix : how can I recover a corrupt tar file from a tape

Tags: unix, solaris, tar, corrupt, data-recovery

I've a tape contains a corrupt tar file.
I'm using Unix SunOS 5.5.1.
So when I run this command :

> dd if=/dev/rmt/0 of=/tmp/outputfile.tar

I get this error message :

> warning /pci@1f, 0/pci@1/pci@1/sunw, isptwo@4/st@4,0 (st4):
>       Error for command : read Error Level: Fatal
>       Requested Block : 11900 Error Block : 11900
>       Vendor : TANDBERG             Serial Number: =:CREATED081
>       Sense Key: Media Error
>       ASC: 0x11 (unrecorded read error), ASCQ: 0x1, FRU: 0x0

Please Help me I really need solution for this problem

Comment: Your tar file is not corrupt, your tape has fatal read errors. You are not going to recover this.

Comment: Really ?!! no way to recover data ? do you mean that the tape is damaged ??

Comment: It might be useful to verify a few things: 1. Do you have the right tape (one that was written something to)  2. Is this a tape written in this drive or some other drive (even if it's exactly the same type) 3. The model and generation of the tape drive and tape medium (to verify they are compatible)

Comment: Please could you explain more the 2 and 3 points ?

Comment: Two (even if they are supposedly identical) tape drives might not be 100% compatible. It's typically easier to read a tape on the same tape drive that wrote it .

Comment: To give you an example: An LTO-3 tape looks very much the same as an LTO-2 tape, but the LTO-3 tape cannot be used in a LTO-2 drive. (But the LTO-3 drive could use a LTO-2 tape as if it were a LTO-2 drive). Even this last backward compatibility is limited: only 2 generations ... (So an LTO-5 drive cannot use an LTO-2 tape).

Comment: Thank you so much for all these details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem ^^' it was the bs format type :D
Data was written in 512 so I did this :

dd if=/dev/rmt/0 of=/tmp/outputfile.tar bs=512 and all is fine :)))

Answer (score 2):

The bad news is that the tape drive is reporting a media error.

Now this still can mean a few things:

1. Bad tape drive

   This is possible, but rather uncommon. To test it: check if it can read other tapes (it wrote itself), or read tapes other drives wrote.
2. Dirty heads

   Tape drives heads do need periodic cleaning. Esp if they are kept in less that spotless conditions this is very important. Cleaning tapes are commercially available, do match them with the right drive and do not overuse them either.
3. Mismatch between tape drive and tape medium

   Different tape formats (e.g. LTO) have generations (e.g. LTO-3), and there is a need for compatibility between the tape medium and the tape drive.
4. Bad tape

   Tapes do wear out, and need replacement to prevent that. Moreover a written tape has a limited shelf life just as well.

   In this last case, you might be able to find a commercial recovery service to try to do something, but I'd not bet the farm on the results ... And data recovery services are expensive ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance, I'll check all these cases